# I want to create a posts widget and be able to select categories

Tags: categories, widgets

Can you please tell me how can I create a wordpress posts widget that outputs posts based on a categories selection ( category checkboxes of all the post categories )

This is in my form function:

```
<?php
foreach ( get_categories() as $category ) : ?>

    <p>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="" name="" />
    <label for=""><?php echo $category->name ?></label>
    </p>    

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For now I just opted for adding categories slug in a text field and use that with `'category_name'` argument in WP_Query

I just can't wrap my head around it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, I figured out how to do it in the end. I'm not really sure if it's the cleanest way ( there aren't that many lines of code though ) but it works just fine. If someone is interested in seing how I did it or wants to help me make the code cleaner, please do tell. Anyway, I'll also take a closer look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Once you can, please post your solution as an answer to this question and accept it if it's the best one.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. To get you started on this site and all SE sites for that matter, feel free to take a [tour] and also visit [help] to learn how these sites operates. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have recently written a widget that

- Gets all the terms from the build in taxonomy `category` and adds them in dropdown in the widget
- Stores the selected category and uses that category in a custom `WP_Query` to get and display posts from the selected category

You can look through it and adjust as needed: (*Required PHP 5.4+*)

(***EDIT:*** Thanks @birgire for spotting the use of `array()` and `[]` notation. Corrected to use only `[]`)

```
<?php
/**
 * Category_Posts widget class
 *
 * Displays posts from a selected category
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
*/
class Category_Posts extends WP_Widget 
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct(
            'widget_category_posts', 
            _x( 'Category Posts Widget', 'Category Posts Widget' ), 
            [ 'description' => __( 'Display a list of posts from a selected category.' ) ] 
        );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_category_posts';

        add_action( 'save_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', [$this, 'flush_widget_cache'] );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        $cache = [];
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_cat_posts', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = [];
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $title          = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Category Posts' );
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );
        $number         = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number ) {
            $number = 5;
        }
        $cat_id         = $instance['cat_id'];
        $random         = $instance['rand'] ? true : false; 
        $excerpt        = $instance['excerpt'] ? true : false; 
        $thumbnail      = $instance['thumbnail'] ? true : false; 

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Category Posts widget.
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         * @see WP_Query::get_posts()
         *
         * @param array $args An array of arguments used to retrieve the category posts.
         */
        if( true === $random ) {

            $query_args = [
                'posts_per_page'    => $number,
                'cat'               => $cat_id,
                'orderby'           => 'rand'
            ];

        }else{  

            $query_args = [
                'posts_per_page'    => $number,
                'cat'               => $cat_id,
            ];

        }
        $q = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'category_posts_args', $query_args ) );

        if( $q->have_posts() ) {

            echo $args['before_widget'];
            if ( $title ) {
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
            }               

            while( $q->have_posts() ) {
                $q->the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> 

                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' ); ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && true === $thumbnail ) { ?>

                        <div class="post-thumbnail">

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                        </div><!--/.post-thumbnail-->

                    <?php   
                    }

                    if( true === $excerpt ) { ?>    

                        <div class="entry-summary">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->

                    <?php } ?>

                </article><!-- #post-## -->

                <?php
            }


            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
            echo $args['after_widget']; 

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_cat_posts', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance                   = $old_instance;
        $instance['title']          = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['number']         = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['cat_id']         = (int) $new_instance['cat_id'];
        $instance['rand']           = $new_instance['rand'];
        $instance['excerpt']        = $new_instance['excerpt'];
        $instance['thumbnail']      = $new_instance['thumbnail'];
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['widget_category_posts']) )
            delete_option('widget_category_posts');

        return $instance;
    }

    public function flush_widget_cache() 
    {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_cat_posts', 'widget');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) 
    {

        $title      = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number     = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $cat_id     = isset( $instance['cat_id'] ) ? absint( $instance['cat_id'] ) : 1;
        $random     = isset( $instance['rand'] ) ? $instance['rand'] : false; 
        $excerpt    = isset( $instance['excerpt'] ) ? $instance['excerpt'] : false; 
        $thumbnail  = isset( $instance['thumbnail'] ) ? $instance['thumbnail'] : false; 
        ?>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_id'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Category Name:' )?></label>
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('cat_id'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('cat_id'); ?>">
                <?php 
                $this->categories = get_categories();
                foreach ( $this->categories as $cat ) {
                    $selected = ( $cat->term_id == esc_attr( $cat_id ) ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
                    $option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $cat->term_id;
                    $option = $option .'">';
                    $option = $option .$cat->name;
                    $option = $option .'</option>';
                    echo $option;
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('rand'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show random posts' ); ?></label>
            <?php $checked = ( $random ) ? ' checked=\"checked\" ' : ''; ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'rand' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'rand' ); ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />    
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('excerpt'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show excerpt. If unchecked, only the title of the post will be displayed' ); ?></label>
            <?php $checked = ( $excerpt ) ? ' checked=\"checked\" ' : ''; ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'excerpt' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'excerpt' ); ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />    
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('thumbnail'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Hide post thumbnail' ); ?></label>
            <?php $checked = ( $thumbnail ) ? ' checked=\"checked\" ' : ''; ?>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'thumbnail' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'thumbnail' ); ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />    
        </p>

    <?php
    }

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', function () 
{
    register_widget( 'Category_Posts' );
});
```

Comment: nice to see the object caching, I guess part of it is already cached via WP_Query ps: just a minor thing: I spotted both the `array()` and `[]` notation

Comment: Thanks for your sharp eyes. Copy and paste error between an older widget. Crap. Need to go through all those and rectify. Hate mixing of syntax, lol.

Comment: it's usually easier noticing stuff like that when doing code reviews for others, than oneself ;-)

Comment: ps: ignore the after widget stuff I wrote ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, ok. Posting from my phone, so I can only see updates to comments and posts once I refresh browser. Only see now you have removed that part :-)